# how to run maven war dependency using tomcat:run?

Tags: maven, tomcat, plugins

I am using maven for my current projects. Now, I have a war dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
   <artifactId>dojo-war</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.1</version>
   <type>war</type>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I don't have any problem when I built the war artifact. For this, I have added this plugin:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <overlays>
                <overlay>
                    <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dojo-war</artifactId>
                    <targetPath>js/dojo-1.8.1</targetPath>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>WEB-INF/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </overlay>
            </overlays>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But, when I run the following mvn command `mvn tomcat7:run` I can not see any javascript resource. It looks like war dependency had not been added.

Could someone help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Emelendez.

You should read this post : http://webtide.intalio.com/2008/07/dojo-toolkit-maven-repository/

Indeed, the dojo-war dependencies allows you to add some files to your sources, but you must specify some extra actions to include it in the final war.

Dependencies, in Maven, can only be in the language you try to compile (well it's not really exact, but this is enough here). If you want to add other resources (files, images, javascript), contained in a zip/war/targz, you must explicitely extract them. This is what is mentionned in the link I provided previously :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack dojo</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dojo</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dojo</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

(Be careful, I'm not sure that this configuration is exact, your dependencie seems to be dojo-war according to your pom.xml, and not dojo as per doc said)

This will extract dojo libs into output directory, and then into your war.